# Is it possible to check if two collumns contain a certain text/string using filters in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, database

I have a database and I would like to display all of the rows that have the word "sales" *CONTAINED* in column B *OR* D.

I tried using advanced filters, but I was only able to show rows that had cells *EQUAL* to "sales" in B or D (e.g. it excluded cells containing things like "the sales").

Using the regular filter function I can only do contained in *one column* or contained in *both* columns, there is not an option that I could find checks if it is contained in *EITHER* column.

It may be worth noting that I was also unable to incorporate =ISNUMBER(SEARCH(substring,text)) into a condition for advanced filtering, but that is a way to check if a cell contains a certain text.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One solution I just thought of involves creating 3 new column E,F,G that that check if column B, column D, or either contains "sales", respectively:

Column E:
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Sales",B8))
Column F:
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Sales",D8))
Column G:
=OR(E8=TRUE, F8=TRUE)

Then Filter by column G all that are TRUE. This is very much a workaround and not very easy to use so if you guys have other suggestions please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I came up with involves making just one extra column and making it contain all of the text in the desired columns through =B8&D8 , then filtering through this column.